# In ClojureScript, how to split string around a regex and keep the matches in the result, without using lookaround?

Tags: regex, clojurescript

I want to split a string on an arbitrary regular expression (similar to `clojure.string/split`) but keep the matches in the result. One way to do this is with lookaround in the regex but this doesn't work well in ClojureScript because it's not supported by all browsers.

In my case, the regex is `#"\{\{\s*[A-Za-z0-9_\.]+?\s*\}\}")`

So for example, `foo {{bar}} baz` should be split into `("foo " "{{bar}}" " baz")`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to choose some special character as a delimiter, insert it into the string during [`replace`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/replace) and then [`split`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/split) on that. Here I used exclamation mark:

Require: `[clojure.string :as s]`

```
(-> "foo {{bar}} baz"
    (s/replace #"\{\{\s*[A-Za-z0-9_\.]+?\s*\}\}" "!$0!")
    (s/split #"!"))

=> ["foo " "{{bar}}" " baz"]
```